# Create a Grid on Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the classic module grid for news in bootstrap 4, it should looks like this:

[image: Image is just a reference]

I can't get that the second column adapt height to the first, and I'm not specifiying a height for the box or the first column, but right now I'd just wanna know what is the best way to achieve this, and if is possible doing this without declaring a static height.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If i may suggest something, You can use css grids instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main>div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/ span 3;
}

.main>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**BooStrap Way**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* To Keep the Aspect Ratio of the stacked Divs */

.rows-container>.row{
   
   /* The "3" depends on how many rows there are*/
   height: calc(100%/3); 
   overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="border container-fluid">
  <div class="border row">
    <div class="border col">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border rows-container col">
      <div class="border row">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>

      </div>
      <div class="border row">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliq</p>

      </div>
      <div class="border row">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="border container-fluid">
  <div class="border row">
    <div class="border col">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border rows-container col">
      <div class="border row">
      </div>
      <div class="border row">
      </div>
      <div class="border row">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="border container-fluid">
  <div class="border row">
    <div class="border col">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border rows-container col">
      <div class="border row">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="border row">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="border row">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll keep waiting for the bootstrap answer, but this is a clean solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time with this problem for bootstrap 4.

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
         <div class="row">
         </div>
         <div class="row">
         </div>
         <div class="row">
         </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```